# How do you add an index to remove the clustered index scan on a table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing, query-optimization

I am trying to optimize a SQL query in SSMS. When I execute it and review the execution plan, there is a clustered index scan on my table called `SalesOrderLineItem`.

Below is my SQL query

```
SELECT
    YEAR(SO.SALESORDERDATE) AS SALESYEAR,
    C.COUNTRYNAME,
    S.SEGMENTNAME,
    SP.FIRSTNAME,
    SP.LASTNAME,
    P.PRODUCTNAME,
    COUNT(*) AS TOTALPRODUCTSALES,
    SUM(
        CASE
            WHEN SLI.PROMOTIONID = 0 THEN 0
            ELSE 1
        END
    ) AS TOTALPROMOTIONALSALES
FROM
    SALESORDERLINEITEM SLI
    INNER JOIN PRODUCT P ON P.PRODUCTID = SLI.PRODUCTID
    INNER JOIN SALESORDER SO ON SO.SALESORDERID = SLI.SALESORDERID
    INNER JOIN SALESREGION SR ON SR.SALESREGIONID = SO.SALESREGIONID
    INNER JOIN SALESPERSON SP ON SP.SALESPERSONID = SR.SALESPERSONID
    INNER JOIN REGION R ON R.REGIONID = SR.REGIONID
    INNER JOIN SEGMENT S ON S.SEGMENTID = R.SEGMENTID
    INNER JOIN COUNTRY C ON C.COUNTRYID = R.COUNTRYID
WHERE
    YEAR(SO.SALESORDERDATE) > 2012
GROUP BY
    YEAR(SO.SALESORDERDATE),
    C.COUNTRYNAME,
    S.SEGMENTNAME,
    SP.FIRSTNAME,
    SP.LASTNAME,
    P.PRODUCTNAME;
```

The clustered index scan has a cost of 48% and a duration of around 0.389s.

I have tried the following and it reduced the cost to 38%, with a duration of around 0.211s, however I would like to design an index to remove the clustered index scan on SalesOrderLineItem.

```
CREATE  INDEX IDX ON SALESORDERLINEITEM (PRODUCTID, PROMOTIONID, SALESORDERID);

GO

SELECT
    YEAR(SO.SALESORDERDATE) AS SALESYEAR,
    C.COUNTRYNAME,
    S.SEGMENTNAME,
    SP.FIRSTNAME,
    SP.LASTNAME,
    P.PRODUCTNAME,
    COUNT(*) AS TOTALPRODUCTSALES,
    SUM(
        CASE
            WHEN SLI.PROMOTIONID = 0 THEN 0
            ELSE 1
        END
    ) AS TOTALPROMOTIONALSALES
FROM
    SALESORDERLINEITEM SLI
    INNER JOIN PRODUCT P ON P.PRODUCTID = SLI.PRODUCTID
    INNER JOIN SALESORDER SO ON SO.SALESORDERID = SLI.SALESORDERID
    INNER JOIN SALESREGION SR ON SR.SALESREGIONID = SO.SALESREGIONID
    INNER JOIN SALESPERSON SP ON SP.SALESPERSONID = SR.SALESPERSONID
    INNER JOIN REGION R ON R.REGIONID = SR.REGIONID
    INNER JOIN SEGMENT S ON S.SEGMENTID = R.SEGMENTID
    INNER JOIN COUNTRY C ON C.COUNTRYID = R.COUNTRYID
WHERE
    YEAR(SO.SALESORDERDATE) > 2012
GROUP BY
    YEAR(SO.SALESORDERDATE),
    C.COUNTRYNAME,
    S.SEGMENTNAME,
    SP.FIRSTNAME,
    SP.LASTNAME,
    P.PRODUCTNAME;
```

What do I need to do to remove this and decrease the overall cost/execution time?

Comment: Fix your query first and use a SARGable `WHERE`. `WHERE YEAR(SO.SALESORDERDATE) > 2012` can't use *any* indexes. Why are you not using a date boundary? `WHERE SO.SALESORDERDATE >= '20120101'`

Comment: For query performance help, we need to know your current tables *and indexes* definitions, and please share the query plan via https://pastetheplan.com

Comment: @Charlieface https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SJ5MBBmgs

Comment: And your tables and indexes please, *all of them*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There simply isn't enough info here to give a definitive answer; we don't know the layout of your tables nor the indexes available nor the amount and spread of data in there.

That said, as mentioned by Larnu, don't use `WHERE function(field) = ...`, it makes it (virtually) impossible to optimally use indexes on said `field`. Going by the plan provided you already did that.

From the plan it looks like you're having

- a table-scan on `SALESORDER` because of the filter on `SO.SALESORDERDATE` and the fact you also need `SO.SALESREGIONID` and `SALESORDERID` on top of `SO.SALESORDERDATE` from that table. Adding a covering index might help out here.
- The reason the `SALESORDERLINEITEM` part of costly is because it's that big. The system has to go through near 125 million row in a rather non-optimal way, the fact that your query runs in sub-second is in fact pretty impressive if you think about it.
- You already managed to get rid of the Clustered Index Scan on the `SALESORDERLINEITEM` table by adding your index but the reason the index is chosen over the table is probably because it's 'slimmer' than the actual table, not so much because it's helping as 'an index'. I would suggest to rather put `SALESORDERID` in front as then the system will more likely be able to first filter on the requested year in `SALESORDER` and use this already limited list to only have to read the necessary records from `SALESORDERLINEITEM` based on the corresponding `SALESORDERID` values.

So, try this:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_test ON SALESORDERLINEITEM (SALESORDERID, PRODUCTID) INCLUDE (PROMOTIONID);
CREATE INDEX idx_test ON SALESORDER (SALESORDERDATE, SALESORDERID) INCLUDE (SALESREGIONID);

SELECT
    YEAR(SO.SALESORDERDATE) AS SALESYEAR,
    C.COUNTRYNAME,
    S.SEGMENTNAME,
    SP.FIRSTNAME,
    SP.LASTNAME,
    P.PRODUCTNAME,
    COUNT(*) AS TOTALPRODUCTSALES,
    SUM(
        CASE
            WHEN SLI.PROMOTIONID = 0 THEN 0
            ELSE 1
        END
    ) AS TOTALPROMOTIONALSALES
FROM
    SALESORDERLINEITEM SLI
    INNER JOIN PRODUCT P ON P.PRODUCTID = SLI.PRODUCTID
    INNER JOIN SALESORDER SO ON SO.SALESORDERID = SLI.SALESORDERID
                            AND SO.SALESORDERDATE >= Convert(datetime, '20120101')
    INNER JOIN SALESREGION SR ON SR.SALESREGIONID = SO.SALESREGIONID
    INNER JOIN SALESPERSON SP ON SP.SALESPERSONID = SR.SALESPERSONID
    INNER JOIN REGION R ON R.REGIONID = SR.REGIONID
    INNER JOIN SEGMENT S ON S.SEGMENTID = R.SEGMENTID
    INNER JOIN COUNTRY C ON C.COUNTRYID = R.COUNTRYID
    
GROUP BY
    YEAR(SO.SALESORDERDATE),
    C.COUNTRYNAME,
    S.SEGMENTNAME,
    SP.FIRSTNAME,
    SP.LASTNAME,
    P.PRODUCTNAME;
```

Post your new plan after applying this to see if (and how) it worked out.

PS: The reason I'm adding `PRODUCTID` to the index on `SALESORDERLINEITEM` too is because it then can fetch those values pre-sorted; MAYBE the optimizer can put that to good use when further joining to the `PRODUCT` table. Same with `SALESORDERID` on the `SALESORDER` index